# parametric aliases in csh to add export command

Tags: alias, tcsh, csh

I'm trying to find a way to translate functions to `csh`/`tcsh` aliases, since they lack functions but have parametric aliases.  As a first step I'm trying to create an `export` command.

Here's what I've got so far

```
alias export 'setenv `echo \!:1 | cut -d'=' -f1` `echo \!:1 | cut -d'=' -f2`'
```

but I'm baffled as to why it's not working.  I'm quite new to their syntax so I might be making a mistake that would be obvious to an experienced (`t`)`csh` user.  Here's the result:

```
% export key=value
setenv: Syntax Error.
```

If I do almost the same thing, but use `echo` instead of `setenv`, it works:

```
alias export 'echo `echo \!:1 | cut -d'=' -f1` `echo \!:1 | cut -d'=' -f2`'
% export key=value
key value
```

That seems to confirm that everything should work, and it should get translated into `setenv key value`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One problem is you're using single quotes (`'`), not double quotes (`"`), the backtick is *only* executed inside double quotes. So, `setenv` gets the *literal string* ``echo \!:1 | cut -d'=' -f1` `echo \!:1 | cut -d'=' -f2``; this is also what `echo` gets, which parses the backticks, which is why that works :-) ... I don't know how to get it working beyond that, though ... tcsh syntax can be so confusing!

Answer (score 1):

```
alias export 'eval setenv `echo \!:1 | cut -d'=' -f1` `echo \!:1 | cut -d'=' -f2`'
```

Comment: Hi! You could make your answer much more helpful by explaining how it works.